# How to install gitg 0.3.3 on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, git

I want to install `gitg` version `0.3.3` on Ubuntu 14.04. How can I do that?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file

Comment: It's not that simple. A newer Gitg version will also require newer GTK and Gnome libraries. It's probably easier to upgrade to a newer Ubuntu release.

Answer (score 1):

Download the gitg 0.3.3 tar/zip file from [gnome](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gitg)

- [zip file](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gitg/snapshot/gitg-0.3.3.zip)
- [tar file](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gitg/snapshot/gitg-0.3.3.tar.xz)

And follow these steps:

```
tar Jxf gitg-0.3.3.tar.xz
cd gitg-0.3.3
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Also, make sure you have all the dependencies installed.