# how to get all gitg 0.3.3 dependencies

Tags: package-management, dependencies, muon-package-manager

I want to install gitg (0.3.3) and followed the steps explained here: 
[How to install gitg 0.3.3 on Ubuntu 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/512818/how-to-install-gitg-0-3-3-on-ubuntu-14-04/512829#512829)

...but I seem to miss dependencies, that are not in the repositories of the package manager.

```
configure: error: Package requirements (
    gthread-2.0 >= 2.38
    glib-2.0 >= 2.38
    gobject-2.0 >= 2.38
    gmodule-2.0 >= 2.38
    gio-2.0 >= 2.38
    gio-unix-2.0 >= 2.38
    gobject-introspection-1.0 >= 0.10.1
    libgit2-glib-1.0 >= 0.0.18
    gtk+-3.0 >= 3.12.0
    webkit2gtk-3.0 >= 2.2
    gee-0.8
    json-glib-1.0
) were not met:

No package 'gthread-2.0' found
No package 'glib-2.0' found
No package 'gobject-2.0' found
No package 'gmodule-2.0' found
No package 'gio-2.0' found
No package 'gio-unix-2.0' found
No package 'gobject-introspection-1.0' found
No package 'libgit2-glib-1.0' found
No package 'gtk+-3.0' found
No package 'webkit2gtk-3.0' found
No package 'gee-0.8' found
No package 'json-glib-1.0' found
Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables LIBGITG_CFLAGS
and LIBGITG_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

I don't understand the comments at the end and also I am not sure, if there is a better way than google every single dependency and how to install it.

I've tried this with the first two (gthread, glib) and learned, that the names for the packages differ in the package manager - for instance *glib2.0* is called *libglib2.0* and from 11 possible packages with each different postfixes (e.g. -bin) there are 4 installed (I have version 2.0 but I need version 2.38 or greater, right?).

To find out, what packages for one dependency I need and that for all 12 dependencies is too komplex for me, "just to install a program".

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you not just do `sudo apt-get install gitg`?

Comment: the version from the official repository is old (0.2.7). Developer writes: "Install gitg from package repositories of your Gnu/Linux distribution.

    For Debian based systems using apt-get package management: apt-get install gitg

    For RPM based systems using yum package management: yum install gitg 

Note: The gitg installed thus will be an older version written in C and differs heavily in code and features from the gitg available from git master."

Comment: Did you manage to install this? I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: unfortunately not. For git management I switched to smartgit / webstorm

Answer (score 5):

One way to get *most* of the build dependencies would be to run `sudo apt-get build-dep gitg`. This would install all of the build dependencies needed to compile `gitg`.

However, note that because of the old version (0.2.7), there might be some dependencies installed that aren't needed, and some dependencies that are needed but not installed.